# Cannot post data to Web API service method using Delphi

Tags: c#, web-services, delphi, indy

I am having a lot of problems performing a simple post of data to a C# WEB API Web Service using Delphi (I have Embarcadero® Delphi 10.1 Berlin Version 24.0.22858.6822)

My Web API service controller is shown below

As you can see I have a class InvoiceBreakdownParameters which contains the parameters required for my method.

The idea is for this object to be created as a JSON string in my Delphi application and this is then passed to the method in the controller

```
namespace STC.MicroServices.WebAPI.Controllers
{
    using System.Web.Http;

    public class InvoiceBreakdownParameters
    {
        public string SessionID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; }
    }

    [RoutePrefix("api/CostCalculation")]
    public class CostCalculationController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public string GetBreakdownForSessionObject(InvoiceBreakdownParameters parameters)
        {
            return "Data Obtained With parameters: " + parameters.SessionID + "CustomerID : " + parameters.CustomerID;
        }
    }
}
```

The code below shows how I post to the web service

```
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  RequestBody: TStream;
  ResponseBody: string;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    RequestBody := TStringStream.Create('{"SessionID":"sessionID","CustomerID":321,"StartDate":"02-01-2017","EndDate": "29-01-2017","MeterID":105,"InvoiceID":-282,"InvoiceNumber":"104637803"}',
  TEncoding.UTF8);

    HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    ResponseBody := HTTP.Post('http://127.0.0.1:56638/api/CostCalculation/GetBreakdownForSessionObject/',
    RequestBody);

    memo1.Text := ResponseBody;
    memo1.Text := memo1.Text + HTTP.ResponseText;
  finally
     RequestBody.Free;
     HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Whenever I try to call this code I get

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error.

This should be so simple do to and yet its wasted me hours!

I have tried with both GetBreakdownForSessionObject and GetBreakdownForSessionObject/

Can anyone see something I have missed?

Paul

PS I have edited the JSON to be Delphi friendly and I still get the same error.  This is really frustrating!  Is there no way to get more information?  I cant even get anything out of Fiddler!

Comment: Delphi does not use escape characters in a string, the slashes are actually sent to the webservice...

Comment: I have corrected the JSON and get the same error

Comment: You might try adding a proxy to the Indy component. 127.0.0.1 and port 8888(you might also need to set it up in fiddler, I forget). That should get it through fiddler so you can at least see what you're sending.

Comment: Your code also need to set the `Position` property of the `TStream`  (e.g. `RequestBody.Position := 0;` or using `Seek` method `RequestBody.Seek(0, soBeginning);` ) before you send the `Post` Request

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string:

```
'{\"SessionID\":\"sessionID\",\"CustomerID\":1}"'
```

However, you are using escape characters in this string. This is actually wrong, and making it invalid JSON.

Remove those escape characters, and make it just plain JSON, like this:

```
'{"SessionID":"sessionID","CustomerID":1}"'
```

You only need to use them if a string value in the JSON needs it, but not the full JSON itself. It could also be that you have the syntax of Pascal confused with that of C#. Delphi doesn't use strings the same way, and the only escape character in Delphi strings is `'`.

---

In addition, you should be resetting your stream's position back to `0` before assigning it to the request...

```
RequestBody.Position := 0;
ResponseBody := HTTP.Post('http://127.0.0.1:56638/api/CostCalculation/GetBreakdownForSessionObject/', RequestBody);
```

Without setting this to `0` first, you're actually sending an empty post stream, because loading data into a stream moves the position to the end. When the stream is sent, it sends from wherever the current position is.

Comment: Please see my amended JSON still get the same error

Comment: @Paul Well then you must have more than one issue.